# Access dictionary several times or store in temporary variable

Tags: python, dictionary

Say, I need to use some value from Python dictionary several times in one piece of code. What are the best practices?

Access dictionary once, store value in some temporary variable and use this variable:

```
value = d['my_key']

do_some_work(value)
do_some_other_work(value)
and_again(value)
```

or access dictionary everytime a need this value:

```
do_some_work(d['my_key'])
do_some_other_work(d['my_key'])
and_again(d['my_key'])
```

Comment: the first obviously.

Comment: The first is easier to read for a coder, but since it's a dictionnary, I don't think it would have any impact on the execution time.

Comment: Ev. Kounis, is it more effective? Doesn't it make code less readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach leads to more readable functions when called, in particular when the key of the dictionary is long or not self explanatory. However, the reader will always have to check the origin of the variable if he's not willing to blindly trust the name of the variable. So why not calling the dictionary directly then?

Personally, I use both approaches according to the use case. If the key or dictionary names are long or not sufficiently self-explanatory, I create a temporary variable. Otherwise, I access the dictionary directly when calling the functions.

Comment: Thanks, that answer seems reasonable to me

Answer (score 1):

For a dict, the average time complexity of accessing an item is constant O(1), see 
[Python Time Complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

So, I wouldn't expect much difference in performance.